# iterate script execution: A call B, B call A

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a script `scriptA.sh` that if a variable assume a certain value, it has to execute another script `scriptB.sh` that execute something and then call a `scriptA.sh`, that will call a `scriptB.sh` and so on.

I draw the execution:

```
ScriptA - ScriptB         
   |
   |
   _
            |
            _
   |
   |
   _
            |
            _
```

I have tried in this way but process are never closed

```
ScriptA.sh
./scriptB.sh &
exit

ScriptB.sh
./scriptA.sh &
exit
```

And also this way but process are never closed

```
ScriptA.sh
./scriptB.sh && exit

ScriptB.sh
./scriptA.sh && exit
```

Any suggestion?

The actual scripts:

scriptA.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
val=123
directory_path=`pwd`
script_name=$0
if [ $val -eq 123 ];then
  echo "call B and exit"
  ./scriptB.sh $directory_path $script_name && exit 0
fi
```

scriptB.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory_path=$1
exec_command=$2
cd
cd $directory_path
echo "call A and exit"
$exec_command && exit 0
```

Comment: You don't have a proper end condition on the recursion?

Comment: can you add the actual bash-code to your question?

Comment: @Kusalananda no I haven't a proper end condition: ScriptA is in a while true loop and if a value is over the threshold then ScriptA call ScriptB and terminate. The ScriptB execute, then call ScriptA and terminate.

Comment: @MichaelD.
_scriptA.sh_
`#!/bin/bash  

val=123

directory_path=\`pwd\`
script_name=$0

if [ $val -eq 123 ];then

 echo "call B and exit"
 ./scriptB.sh $directory_path $script_name && exit 0

fi `

_scriptB.sh_
`#!/bin/bash

directory_path=$1
exec_command=$2

cd 
cd $directory_path

echo "call A and exit"
$exec_command && exit 0
`

Comment: nice endless loop. exit will never be called

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
To keep your structure, you might create these two files:

scripta.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./controller.sh a
```

scriptb.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./controller.sh b
```

---

Here is a suggestion to make it easier:

controller.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# run   ./controller.sh a   to run a/b
# run   ./controller.sh b   to run b/a
if [ "$1" == "a" ]; then
  ./ascript.sh      
  ./bscript.sh

elif [ "$1" == "b" ]; then
  ./bscript.sh
  ./ascript.sh
else
  echo "choose a or b ./controller.sh [a|b]"
  exit 255
fi
exit 0
```

ascript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script a"
# add code here
```

bscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script b"
# add code here
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this isn't useful for me because I can't change the script structure with the insertion of a controller...

Comment: edited/updated my answer: "Do One Thing and Do It Well" and "Keep it Simple, Stupid." are  some *nix rules which you might want to follow.